# Changing the stylesheet in a div with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

Using a chrome extension, I want to change the stylesheet associated with an individual div.

For example, the current page looks like:

```
<div id="footer">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="linktostylesheet.css">
...
</div>
```

I would like to not use the that stylesheet, and insert my own:

```
<div id="footer">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link to my new stylesheet.css">
...
</div>
```

I am a little lost with this type of programming. So far I have the following snippet of code in my content script, however I don't think I have the right idea.

```
d = document.getElementById("footer").getContentDocument();
d.styleSheets[d.styleSheets.length].href = 'newstylesheet.css';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<link>` element should be child of `<head>` element. You can select the `link` element by beginning value of `href` attribute, set `href` of element to new value.

```
document.querySelector("link[href^=linktostylesheet]").href = "newstylesheet.css";
```